# Looking for an idiom that expresses something that looks bad at the outset but turns out okay

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example: I heard a noise downstairs in the middle of the night and feared it was an intruder. When I checked it out, I found the noise was from a plant on my porch knocked over by the wind.

Comment: *What a relief!*

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a *[false alarm](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/false-alarm)*

> an occasion on which danger is perceived but fails to materialize

*Collins*

It also sounds a bit like Macbeth's lament about all of life, *[full of sound and fury, signifying nothing](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/macbeth.5.5.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

***More scared (or afraid) than hurt***

> *She was more scared than hurt*.`["Old Ebenezer" by Opie
>   Read](http://www.finedictionary.com/hurtful.html)

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

> Its bark was worse than its bite.

Here's a [link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bark+is+worse+than+bite).